# Converting doc to pdf

Tags: linux, bash, documents

I try to convert a doc file to a pdf file with the linux bash.
I tried different ways like jodconverter, ghostscript, postscript and so on, but all didn't work as espected.
Additionally I can say that I have only the bash.

Is there any way, which you can advice me?

Comment: Thanks, but nothing works for me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `unoconv`?

I did, and it seems to work. This is what I did (after lots of googling :):

1. I installed unoconv (I had Libre Office installed)
2. Booted to console (no X server running)
3. Started soffice in headless mode with this command:

   /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin -headless -nofirststartwizard -accept="socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.Service" &

After that, simple `unoconv document.doc` converted document.doc to document.pdf (pdf is default output format).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get following error "unoconv: UnoException during conversion: URL seems to be an unsupported one.
The provided document cannot be converted to the desired format.". I searched for it at google, but I can't find any solution.

Comment: libreoffice -headless -convert-to pdf document.doc    How about this?

Comment: The argument headless is deprecated. --headless is the new argument. :) I got following error: stat: cannot read file system information for `test.doc': Input/output error

Comment: Hm, it could be some kind of a file system problem...

I assume test.doc is in your current directory, try
    stat test.doc    
It could be that you are not able to access that file at all.

Comment: Now it seems that the command work, but I can't find the output or an argument for it.

Comment: If it doesn't create output file, then it doesn't work :) 

It might be a simple ownership/permission problem, did you check that? 

Maybe you should first try something simpler, like creating simple text file, and if you are sure you can access it and read it, try converting it to pdf.

For example, something like this:

`echo "This is a test" > test.txt` and after that

    `libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf test.txt`    

and see what happens. It should create file  test.pdf .

Comment: Nothing happened, there is no output file. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: It's hard to say, but maybe you misunderstood something here:

You shouldn't run unoconv and soffice.bin prior to using "libreoffice --headless ..."
The behaviour you described (no output at all) in my experience happened when soffice.bin 
was already running.  So, `ps -e | grep soffice` shouldn't give any output.

Also, check that you have sufficient permissions, but I guess you already did that.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that yet, I had tried again but with the same results. I am running that command in /tmp.

Comment: Well, if there is absolutely no output, and you are sure permissions are set up correctly,
(you can access the file you are trying to convert and you have write permissions to /tmp)
you can try running strace. 
Something like `strace -f -o libre.log libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf test.doc`
After that you should have  libre.log file with log of what was happening.

Comment: Here is my stacktrace, I hope you can help me with these informations: http://pastebin.com/pKUA4F44

Comment: Well, I was hoping to find something obvious, but it didn't happen. But, there are some log.txt files mentioned in strace, maybe they hold something useful. And take a look here: [link](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=491456#122) and  [link](http://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/users/msg12129.html). Regarding unoconv, I guess running libreoffice (it's a simple shell script which starts soffice) is better option than unoconv, because unoconv still relies on open/libre office built-in converting features, and another layer of complexity is probably even more error-prone.

Answer (score 10):

```
lowriter --convert-to pdf *.doc
```

lowriter is the 'writer' program from LibreOffice (maybe your distro's LibreOffice package differs - check this!).

Comment: Thanks but I haven't a running X-Server.

Answer (score 4):

Get into the folder that has your LibreOffice and run this in terminal.

```
./soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir destination_path source_path/*.doc
```

Or using Unoconv

> unoconv -f pdf File.doc